# Gulp Equivalent of grunt.package

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

Is there a gulp equivalent of `grunt.package`?

I would like to get some of the meta data as a variable from my `package.json` file.

Comment: Can I ask why the down vote? If I'm doing something wrong I'd like to know what.

Comment: My guess is because it's [already in the recipes for gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-external-config-file.md), but I don't think that excuses a down vote, because documentation is pretty rough right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this to your gulpfile:

```js
var pkg = require('./package.json');
```

That's it!  That's one of the great things about gulp, no need to use some specialized API for simple things.

You can also require `bower.json` the same way, if you want.

[I've also been using an external file](https://gist.github.com/OverZealous/8343073) to store all the specific build information, so it's more flexible to reuse my gulpfile later.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I suppose I should have figured that out but I'm still getting used to the change.